# Testing packages that depend upon Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, eloquent, phpunit

This is my scenario: I have two Laravel apps that both depend on a set of custom (in-house) components. These components sit in a separate git repository and are packaged as a Composer package `C`, which I include in my Laravel apps.

Now my package `C` makes heavy use of Eloquent to do database operations. I would like to unit-test `C` wit Laravel's PHPUnit testing environment, but without bloating `C` to a whole Laravel installation.

As a first step, I Composer-required `laravel`, `phpunit` and some other packages that seemed relevant, but it still looks like a long way to do actual database testing (where would I, for instance, specify my database connection?).

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: If Laraval implements interfaces for the Eloquent classes then manually import those interfaces from Laraval into your test harness, then use PHPUnit's mocking API to generate mocks on the fly.  

That's assuming that Laraval actually does implement interfaces for Eloquent, I've never used it so I can't say for sure.  If it doesn't use interfaces then you'll have to pull in the actual Eloquent code and mock from that.  

All of this assumes you're using dependency injection to insert Eloquent into your classes.  You are using dependency injection, right?